# How to specify a disk type for workers in Google Dataflow?

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow

In the doc there is a [option workerDiskType](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/options/DataflowPipelineWorkerPoolOptions#getWorkerDiskType--) but I can't make it work. I tried to use persistent SSD. Each time I try something I get a `400` http code without explanation.

I tried all of those values:

- zones/$ZONE/diskTypes/pd-ssd
- zones/$ZONE/disks/pd-ssd
- projects/$PROJECT/zones/$ZONE/diskTypes/pd-ssd
- projects/$PROJECT/zones/$ZONE/disks/pd-ssd

What is the correct format? Does this option works?

The answer I have from Dataflow is not really helpful:

```
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "reason" : "badRequest"
  } ],
  "message" : "Request contains an invalid argument.",
  "status" : "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"compute.googleapis.com/projects//zones//diskTypes/pd-ssd" is the correct identifier for SSDs